# Change CalendarView TypeFace programmatically?

Tags: android, calendarview

How can I change the typeface of day numbers and month and year text in CalendarView programmatically? Btw I am using my own typeface created from assets.

[image]

(Note: I need to change text font in CalendarView widget, not same as DatePicker that contains three NumberPickers)